# loop is not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I m Working in cakephp and want to looping with certain variable which is actually in string format i cast it in int but still it not response while i run,means inside loop 'hi' is not printing .......

```
            $one = array();
            echo intval($tolatitude[0]);
            $start=intval($fromlatitude[0]);
            $end=intval($tolatitude[0]);

            for($i=(int)$start;$i<(int)$end;$i++)
            {
                 //$one = $this->Place->find('all', array(
                  //'conditions' => array('Place.Latitude' => $i)
                  //));
                 //debug($one);
                 echo "Hi i m in loop";
            }
```

if any one know plZ help me....

Comment: "plz" isn't a word, please stop using it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably not due to the fact you're using CakePHP. The loop probably doesn't fire because the value of `$end` is lower than `$start`.

If I substitute `$fromlatitude[0]` and `$tolatitude[0]` with real values, `1` and `5` respectively the message *"Hi i m in loop"* is printed 4 times.

So check the values of `$fromlatitude[0]` and `$tolatitude[0]`. Do those array keys actually exist and what values do they hold?

```
$start=intval(1);
$end=intval(5);

for($i=(int)$start;$i<(int)$end;$i++) {
  echo "Hi i m in loop";
}
```